# Upgrading GKE Kubernetes node version to v1.1.1, master still at v1.0.7 despite conflicting release notes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

We're trying to take advantage of some of the new features in the v1.1.1 Kubernetes release by upgrading our cluster running on Google Container Engine.

On the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#supported_kubernetes_api_versions) Google states that cluster masters are currently running v1.1.1. However, when trying to upgrade our existing cluster nodes (following the [cluster upgrade docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade)), I get the following the trace:

`Failed to start node upgrade: Desired node version (1.1.1) cannot be greater than current master version (1.0.7)`

This is confirmed by running `kubectl version`:

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.1", GitCommit:"92635e23dfafb2ddc828c8ac6c03c7a7205a84d8", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.7", GitCommit:"6234d6a0abd3323cd08c52602e4a91e47fc9491c", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

All the while, the gcloud console reports a cluster api version of `1.0.6`.

Are the master upgrades still in process for existing clusters? Does a timeline exist on that? Earlier release notes mention a 1 week runway for existing cluster version upgrades; we've just surpassed that window from the release date of v1.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release notes state that "Kubernetes v1.1.1 is the default version for *new* clusters" (emphasis added). Existing clusters will be upgraded from 1.0 to 1.1 in the coming weeks. If you want to take advantage of the 1.1 features immediately you can create a new cluster at 1.1 or contact us on the #google-containers channel on [Slack](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#slack) to ask for your cluster to be upgraded sooner.